# Nothing to be done for "Makefile"

Tags: makefile

I am supposed to write a Makefile for a project I need to do. I have it all done but when I try to do it, I get the following output:

> make: Nothing to be done for `Makefile'

What might be the cause of this?

Here's my Makefile file:

```
###########################################################
# Makefile for XXXXX
# name1, name2
# account1, account2
###########################################################
EXEC = a1
CC = /opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc
$(EXEC):
    $(CC) -o $(EXEC) a1.cpp a1.h a1.sic
    rm -f *.o
clean:
    rm -f *.o core diss $(EXEC)
#######################[ EOF: Makefile ]###################
```

Edit:
Thanks to a kind user, I now know what happened.

Now I have the following output

```
/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc -o a1 a1.cpp a1.h a1.sic
ld: fatal: file a1.cpp: unknown file type
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to a1
make: *** [a1] Error 2
```

Can you please help?

Comment: You're trying to compile C++ code with a C compiler; this does not work well.  Use a C++ compiler, probably `/opt/SUNWspro/bin/CC` (all caps).  You don't normally list header files on the compiler command line.  And I'm not sure who knows what a `.sic` file is.

Comment: The professor asked us to put every file. A `.sic` file is for an assembler we're using.

Comment: Well, if the `.sic` file is translated for you, fine.  The `.h` file should probably not be on the command line.  There's a chance it may be recognized and rendered harmless, but if there's a problem with an unrecognized file type for `a1.h`, then you know it wasn't OK.  I've not seen `.sic` used for assembler.  If the Sun compiler recognizes it, great.  If not, you've some more work to do in the makefile (possibly adding rules for converting `.sic` assembler to `.o` object files.

Comment: A makefile automates tasks you would otherwise perform from the command line. So before you write a makefile to do something, *you must know how to do it without a makefile*. Try to build `a1` with a command like `cc -o a1 a1.cpp a1.sic`, and don't try to write a makefile until that works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Are you typing `make Makefile` for some reason?  Don't.  Just type `make`.  `make a1` or `make -f Makefile` will work for your situation, too, but why bother with the extra typing?

As an aside, it's a bit weird to include header files on your compile line.  Also, your makefile doesn't specify any dependencies, which is kind of the whole reason to have one in the first place...

Edit:  to answer your new question, don't compile C++ code with a C compiler.  That said, I'm not sure about the link error you're getting.  Is `a1.cpp` not a normal source file (type `file a1.cpp` to find out)?

It seems like you are having very fundamental problems.  Maybe starting with a good beginner book would be useful?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a dependency in here?

Comment: Check out the `make` manual.  It has everything you need to know.

Comment: Since the C compiler doesn't know what to do with the `.cpp` file (or the `.h` file or the `.sic` file) it passes them on to the loader without compiling.  The loader doesn't know what to do with them and complains that it doesn't know what a `.cpp` file is either.